# Move a folder into solution and play files

Tags: wpf, filepath

In my project, I currently have a path to my files at my desktop.
I want to move the folder inside the project but only gets an error.

My actual path now:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/v80770/Desktop/Movies/");
```

I want to be able to get the files by writing;

```
 string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"./Resources/Movies");
```

Error message I get:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\v\Desktop\Applikation\SourceCode\Applications\***\*** ***\****.App\bin\x86\Debug\Resources\Movies'.'
```

Comment: If you are using a relative path, shouldn't it just be "./Resources/Movies" ?

Comment: I updated the question with the error message I get now.

Comment: try using Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Resources/Movies") and see if that helps.

Comment: I get the same error :(

Comment: This is a debugging issue, when you are debugging, look at System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and see where it is pointing at, and then see if you actually have a Resources/Movies subdirectory there in the filesystem.

Comment: Nope, I had no Resources/Movies subdirectory there in the filesystem. And it still does not working :(

Comment: Confused... So you don't actually have a resources/movies directory already, are you just trying to copy files to a new directory via code? Here is an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders

Comment: @Emma: Did you actually add the files to your project before you compiled and run the app? Of course there will no files in this folder unless you copy them there.

Comment: Problem solved :D

Comment: @Emma: So what was the solution?

Comment: I created a folder in bin degug and referenced it in my code.